# How do I make a time machine backup drive a normal hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, monterey, logic

I have been trying to relocate my Logic Pro X's Apple Loops library to a different hard drive. I have everything figured out, except for the problem in which Logic will not accept the secondary hard drive I am trying to select. It says that it cannot use the secondary hard drive because it is a "Time Machine Backup Drive." I found a couple possible solutions, but all of them are describing buttons that are either hidden for me, or were removed recently.
I am on an M1 Mac on version 12.3.1, and I cannot find a button anywhere that lets me change the hard drive to just a standard hard drive and not a Time Machine Backup Drive.
One solution that I saw involved deleting everything on my secondary hard drive. However, I cannot copy or save the things on it, because I do not have enough space on any of my other hard drives to store the data from the secondary hard drive.
Is there any way to make a Time Machine Backup Drive a normal hard drive *without* deleting everything on it?
If so, am I missing any buttons, or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you intend to repartition it to allow Logic files on 'half' of it, or reformat it entirely & remove it from your Time Machine pool?

Comment: This is not a recommended path.  [Apple recommends that the drive not be used for anything else](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250). I’d get a new disk for your Logic files